# How do I remove my visa from the App Store which has been declined?

Tags: apple-store

Every time I try to download an app, it comes up with a message displaying "Verification Required". So I try to verify my information and it says it's declined. I've made purchases before and never had problems, I don't have any outstanding payments due. I'm only 17 for gods sake.

There is no "None" option when trying to cancel the payment option.

Also I cannot update or download apps, so snapchat won't let me into it because it says "Waiting..." And it's frustrating me. Please help asap!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add a functioning payment method to get past that. Even if you never intend to buy anything, if the account was originally set up with a credit card, a valid credit card has to be on file to download anything (including updates and free apps).